# PCIe expansion cards for dual NVME M.2 drives

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, m.2

I have a MPG Z690 Carbon Motherboard.

Here are the specs of the PCIe slots.

PCI_E1 & PCI_E2 slots (From CPU)
Support PCIe 5.0
Support x16/ x0, x8/ x8

Will two PCIe adapter cards for dual M.2 drives each work to give me 4 independent drives? I am not sure what the last line indicates so I need to be sure.

Could someone confirm this combination for me?

Comment: “I am not sure what the last line indicates so I need to be sure.” What last line? What do you mean?

Comment: A dual M.2 card would split a x8 PCIe by 2. You have a total of x16 PCIe 5 lanes split between 2 slots.

Comment: PCIe 5.0 Support x16/ x0, x8/ x8, I’m confused by x0, x8 x8. I think it indicates that each of the PCIe slots can accept an adapter card with two individual M. 2 drives. I have no idea what the X0 indicates

Answer (score 0):

> PCI_E1 & PCI_E2 slots (From CPU) Support PCIe 5.0 Support x16/ x0, x8/ x8

Means that the slots will operate in one of two modes.

- x16/ x0, where slot PCI_E1 operates at x16 and PCI_E2 operates at x0 (nothing connected)
- x8/ x8, where slot PCI_E1 operates at x8 and PCI_E2 operates at x8, both slots get 8 lanes each.

If your m.2 cards have a PCIe splitter on them that takes in an x8 link and splits it to two x4 links then yes it absolutely should work.